# Ruby on Rails API namespace as default path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, namespaces

I am setting up my Rails API server following this tutorial: [building-awesome-rails-apis-part-1](https://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2013/06/13/building-awesome-rails-apis-part-1)

Everything works well, except the part that mentions that it is not necessary to indicate the namespace in the route. Eg.

> Now our URls look like: `http://api.example.com/v1/people` or just
> `http://api.example.com/people` if you don’t use the version, it
> doesn’t interfere with your regular people routes, and it looks great.

When I call `http://api.mydomain.com/v1/therapists/` it works, but when I try to omit the `v1` namespace in the URL it's not working, do I need to do any extra configuration?

I'm using `Rails 6.0.3.4`

This is my specific routes.rb file:

```ruby
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, :path => "", :constraints => {:subdomain => "api"} do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :therapists do
        resources :appointments
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Solution**

As zhisme suggested, I used rack-rewrite gem to do what I wanted.

First, I added the gem to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack-rewrite', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.1'
```

After that I added the configuration in `config/application.rb` file

```
  config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Runtime, Rack::Rewrite) do
    rewrite '/therapists', '/v1/therapists'
  end
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this, you will need to insert inside `Rack` code. There is a gem [rack-rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite) that can do redirects before Rails code execute, thus before rails routes resolving. Check their README for installation.

so modifying README example to your question, you can do something like

```rb
config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Runtime, Rack::Rewrite) do
  rewrite '/api/therapists/appointments', '/api/v1/therapists/appointments'
end
```

or you can make redirects to give your api consumers to know that correct url is a bit different

```rb
config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Runtime, Rack::Rewrite) do
  moved_permanently '/api/therapists/appointments', '/api/v1/therapists/appointments'
end
```

There is quite good [article](https://www.nopio.com/blog/how-to-set-up-redirects-in-a-ruby-rack-application/) describing different solutions, take a look for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you omit the `v1` namespace in the URL, you must also remove it from your routes.rb file.

The quote from the tutorial stated "or just http://api.example.com/people if you don’t use the version", meaning if you don't include the `v1` namespace in the routes.rb file.

Comment: let me edit my question then, is there a way to use a specific version as the default in case I'm having more than 1?